# Bootstrap - Two dropdowns but only the first one I click works

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I've added two bootstrap (4.3.1) dropdown buttons. It doesn't matter which one I click first of the two.The first one I click on works. But the second gives an error and is not working.

> applyStyle.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'setAttribute' of null
> at Object.onLoad (applyStyle.js:66)
> at index.js:69
> at Array.forEach ()
> at new t (index.js:67)
> at c.t.toggle (dropdown.js:176)
> at HTMLAnchorElement. (dropdown.js:381)
> at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
> at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
> at S.fn.init.c._jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (dropdown.js:368)
> at HTMLAnchorElement. (dropdown.js:525)

Below is my code:

```
<div class="top-link" id="menu_usecases">
            <div class="btn-group">
    
                <div class="dropdown show">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Use Cases
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/usecases/cx"><B>Customer Experience</B></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/usecases/sc"><B>Supply Chain</B></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="top-link" id="menu_resources">
            <div class="btn-group">
          
                <div class="dropdown show">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Resources
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/news"><B>News</B></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/resources"><B>Technical Documents</B></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Seems like there's another issue. I just created a snippet with this HTML only and it worked just fine. Could there be something else?

Comment: The error is reffering to this line:

popper.setAttribute('x-placement', placement);

Comment: I have found the problem. I had a piece of javascript in my code to adjust the dropdown position. There was a mistake in that. I was referring to a class when I had to refer to element's unique id.